# building opencv, got undefined reference to avformat_network_init error

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, centos

I am using CentOS6.5, I downloaded opencv-2.4.9, made build directory, and under there, ran 'cmake ..' and 'make'. During the make run, I got this error message.

[image: link error message]

I found avformat_network_init in ffmpeg source, I installed ffmpeg once in my home and then to /usr/lib.  but I don't know how to tell cmake where ffmpeg is installed (include header and library).
Now I see some *.so files from ffmpeg under /usr/lib64. but why can't cmake find the ffmpeg location?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in building OpenCV.  For anyone's reference I post my answer here.
I have had installed ffmpeg in 3 different places before (/usr/local/lib, /usr/local/lib64 and /usr/local). I removed all of them (I ran make uninstall at the build directories I used to install ffmpeg which had been configured with different prefix values).
I also removed ffmpeg that I installed with yum install by running 'rpm -e ffmpeg'. Then I started fresh with installing ffmpeg (to /usr/local). This time it was ok until last part, where make couldn't find javac compiler.
I figured my JAVA_HOME env varailbe was pointing a wrong place so I set JAVA_HOME directory for right place(In my case, /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64). Then the 'make' completed! Then I ran 'make install'